# Inserting data into multiple tables at same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is what I am trying to do:

Let's say I have two tables dbo.source & dbo.destination
I want to copy all records from source to destination IF a certain natural key (unique non clustered) does not exist in the destination. If the insert is successful, then output some values to a temporary buffer table.
Next I want to list all the records from the source which DID have a match in the destination, and copy these as well to the buffer table.

Is there anyway I can achieve this so that the buffer table does not hold redundant data ?

This is my current logic:

Step1: Get records from the source table where the natural key does not match the destination and insert into destination
Insert these into buffer table with flag

```
MERGE INTO dbo.Destination dest USING dbo.Source AS src 
ON dest.Name = src.Name --Natural Key
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (xxx) VALUES (xxx)
OUTPUT src.ID, Inserted.ID, 'flagA'
INTO dbo.Buffer;
```

Step2:
Get records from the source table where the natural key matched the destination
Insert these into buffer with a flag

```
Insert INTO dbo.Buffer
Select src.ID, src.Name, 'flagB'
FROM dbo.Source src 
inner join dbo.Destination dest
on src.Name = dest.Name
```

With this logic, I am getting redundant rows into my buffer, which do not exactly track the inserts as intended. Can anyone critique my sql based on what I am trying to do.

Comment: Note- I use merge and not inserts as I need to be able to utilize 'Output'. Please refer https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8cf1e38e-a29b-4ad7-abc7-b9fe2b987698/insert-into-using-select-with-output-into-multipart-identifier-could-not-be-bound?forum=transactsql

Comment: Why? There are no problems accessing the output table when you use INSERT statements.

Comment: why do not you use `WHEN MATCHED BY TARGET`?

Comment: @LONG Can you please provide an example how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your second query, it also matches the just inserted rows. You should do something like this:

```
Insert INTO dbo.Buffer
Select src.ID, src.name, 'flagB'
FROM dbo.Source src
    inner join dbo.Destination dest on src.Name = dest.Name
where not exists (
    select * from dbo.Buffer b where b.xxx = 'flagA' and b.yyy = src.name
)
```

Or just use when matched by target, as LONG suggested.

Comment: Thanks my brain froze on the 'where not exists' part. I knew I was missing something

Answer (score 3):

You can try it some like it, the dislike of this technique is that you always update one field. Maybe, you need to adapt my example to your needs.

```
DECLARE @Source table (id int identity , myValue varchar(5))
DECLARE @Destination table (id int identity  , myValue varchar(5))
DECLARE @Buffer table (sourceId int , InsertId varchar(5),flag varchar(5))

insert @Source (myValue) values ( 'a') ,( 'e'),( 'i'),( 'o'),( 'u')
insert @Destination (myValue) values ('a') ,('b'),('c')

;merge @Destination t 
using @Source S 
on
t.myValue = s.myValue
when not matched then insert (myValue) values (s.myValue)
when matched then update set myValue = t.myValue
output s.id, inserted.id, case $action when 'INSERT' then 'flagA' else 'flagB' end into @Buffer;


select * from @Destination
select * from @Buffer
```

Result

Destination table

```
id          myValue
----------- -------
1           a
2           b
3           c
4           e
5           i
6           o
7           u
```

Buffer table

```
sourceId    InsertId flag
----------- -------- -----
2           4        flagA
3           5        flagA
4           6        flagA
5           7        flagA
1           1        flagB
```

use this output

```
output s.id, case $action when 'INSERT' then Cast(inserted.id as varchar(5)) else inserted.myValue end , case $action when 'INSERT' then 'flagA' else 'flagB' end into @Buffer;
```

for

```
sourceId    InsertId flag
----------- -------- -----
2           4        flagA
3           5        flagA
4           6        flagA
5           7        flagA
1           a        flagB
```

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly helpful!